# Intercepting RMI calls on server end

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am trying to create a Virtualization service for RMI clients which when deployed will return some customer response. However at the server end i do not have an actual implementation of the RMI interface. Is there any possible way where i can intercept the RMI request to my host and port and checks the method name and parameters and returns mocked response. E.g.

I have interface

```
public interface ICustomer extends Remote {
    public List<Customers> fetchCustomer(int id)
}
```

Client calling code looks something like this

```
Mocker.RMI().mockUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/Customer ").forMethod("fetchCustomer").withId(1).thenReturn(new Customer()).mock()
```

Then i need a way to intercept the request on my server side and check if method name is fetchCustomer and id is 1 then return new Customer() passed in the thenReturn function.

Comment: Why check methods if the client and server share the same remote interface?